# Using scanner to get input whether its String or Int

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter number: ");

while (true) {
    if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
        int i = sc.nextInt();
    } else {
        String i = sc.next();
    }  
}

System.out.println(" "+i);
```

Why cant I use `String i` and `int i` beyond the `while` loop?

Comment: Because of something called "local scope."  `i` is only defined within that `if` block.

Comment: You won't be able to re-use the same variable, nor should you.

Comment: Since your loop is infinite, your attempt to print the variable is unreachable code anyway.

Comment: Im really stuck on a programming homework right now, and I can't seem to figure out what to use. Im supposed to search through an array using search parameters that accept int and String then output all results within that category

Answer (score 0):

You declare the variable inside of your while loop so the variable is scoped to that part of your code only, to make it available behond your while loop you have to declare it before your while loop and than populate it in your while loop

Comment: Thanks, I get it now. Im really stuck on a programming homework right now, and I can't seem to figure out what to use. Im supposed to search through an array using search parameters that accept int and String then output all results within that category.

Answer (score 0):

Please describe what you want to do with this code.
If you just want to get the input from the console and print it, you can just do this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
```

Why did you want to put it into a loop?

And if you want to learn, please consider starting a free course or read a book.

Comment: Oh it was supposed to be just enter "Something". What I want to do is search through an array using search parameters that accept string and int then display all those that match that description.

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/2014/04/check-if-array-contains-a-value-java/... Check it out. See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The variable i cannot be printed outside the while loop because any variables created inside of a loop are LOCAL TO THE LOOP. This means that once you exit the loop, the variable can no longer be accessed! This includes any variables created in the loop signature

[You can refer more from here](https://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html#:%7E:text=Loop%20Scope&text=Any%20variables%20created%20inside%20of,created%20in%20the%20loop%20signature.)